# WooCommerce product - show price when quantity changes

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am fairly new to woocommerce - I've been using it a few months now.  I have a situation where I am using a variable product in addition to dynamic discount plugin.   My discounts are based on percentage and factor in when the quantity changes.  Ideally my customer would like to see the updated product price on the product page rather than waiting for the cart.

1. Is this possible?  I've seen people do variations of this but only with simple products.  The dynamic discount author did not think so - I am writing to ask if there is a generic woocommerce call that can be added to initiate the whole price calculation.
2. If not, is there another option?  I've seen plugins that allow me to write html back to the screen when quantity changes.  At worse I can probably do that (e.g. buy 2 more to discount the price x%)

Comment: Which plugin you are using currently ?

Comment: Mostly everything is possible in Woocommerce… After is just a question of skills and time to be spent. Now when you use a plugin, you get the limitations of that plugin. There is not a generic call as this is based on customer live quantity choice and you should need to use javascript (jquery)…

Comment: I am using Woocommerce Dynamic Pricing plugin.